# Filtering large CSV files using Python - KeyError: False Exception

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

hoping for some insight and help.

I am running into an exception whilst trying to filter multiple very large CSV files and output the results into a new csv file(s).

Initially I was getting an "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'query'
After some research, I understood this was because method "query" is a pandas dataframe method and so I added the line "***df = pd.DataFrame(data)***" which resolved the error however the program is now throwing a "**KeyError: False**" exception and I don't fully understand the reason for it nor how to solve for it.

Any insight as how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated !

```
import pandas as pd

from glob import glob
filenames = glob("mySourceFiles*")
data = [ pd.read_csv(f, dtype = unicode, engine = 'python', 
         sep = ',', quotechar = '"', error_bad_lines = False, encoding = 'Latin-1') for f in filenames]
         
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.query('"Location    " == "LN"').to_csv('myOutputFile.csv')
```

Comment: The Data Frame's column name is not quoted in the query statement. Does `df.query("Location == 'LN'")` work?  It would be helpful to trim leading/trailing white space from the Data Frame's column names, if necessary.

Comment: Try changing `df =` to `df = pd.concat(data)`... your list comprehension builds a list of dfs